# Tramping on the same question for better or more relevant answers?

Tags: discussion

When your question is closed as a dupe, but the original (by a different author) has an an accepted answer that is vague, dated or maybe not acceptable any longer (e.g. possibly the target technology has been modified since then) what's the recommended chain of events to go about getting better answers?

Is the  bounty the best solution, maybe with a comment on the original question stating why you're posting the bounty? If so, how does the right solution get marked (or remarked) if it's not your question?

I've sometimes wished questions were versioned along with the version of the software they are based on.

Comment: I've had this problem before. I usually will end up editing my question to be completely clear that it's not a duplicate, or not answered by the suspected duplicate, and then if it doesn't get reopened, I will flag for diamond moderator attention

Comment: Edit the question and explain that. That's usually enough to ebb the flow of close votes.

Answer (score 5):

If the question is dated or vague, you should create a new question and *make sure you mention why your question is different from the original question*.